# Angular material dateAdapter does not consider different hours/minutes/seconds as a different date

Tags: angular-material, angular7, angular8

I'm building a time extension (hours/minutes/seconds) for angular material DatePicker (beause there aren't any good ones out there yet). The problem is when I update the time in the time component I use the DatePickers **select** method which is the only method to set dates programatically using a Date object.
The problem is Datepickers inner select function does not consider different Hours/Minutes/seconds as a different date, and when supplied with such scenarion it will not update its inner workings.
The following is the select function of Angular Material Datepicker:

```
MatDatepicker.prototype.select = function (date) {
    var oldValue = this._selected;
    this._selected = date;
    // this will eveluate as false since only hours/minuts/seconds are different and not day/month/year
    if (!this._dateAdapter.sameDate(oldValue, this._selected)) { 
        this._selectedChanged.next(date);
    }
};
```

Inside the **sameDate** method they use a method called **compareDate** which check the two dates only by day and month & year:

```
DateAdapter.prototype.compareDate = function (first, second) {
    return this.getYear(first) - this.getYear(second) ||
        this.getMonth(first) - this.getMonth(second) ||
        this.getDate(first) - this.getDate(second);
};
```

This means **select** method will not emit the new date to DatePicker's inner components & parts.

I am using a custom **NativeDateAdapter** and a custom **MatDateFormats** but since the above check want emit the new date these mechanism want be reached.

P.S
Everything works ok when the updated date has a different day/year/month including the custom time formating to include the time parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by simply re-implementing the base classes **compareDate** method using the custom  NativeDateAdapter.

```
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        // format your dates
    }
    compareDate(first: Date, second: Date) {
       // compare first/current date with second/previous date
       // you can implement your logic here.
       return 1;
    }
}
```